# flexbox not working. Id like to make a button(html <button> tab) round

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 questions. I have the code in .js file.

1. I'd like to make button round. I've been trying like below but its still square.
2. I'd like to show buttons(with name underneath) row direction.
   I've given  for each so that className="btn-newroom" can be the parent.

```css
.btn-newroom {
  display: flex;
}

button {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div className="new-room-form">
  <form onSubmit={handleSumbit}>
    <div className="btn-newroom">
      <div>
        <button
          className="create-room-btn"
          type="submit"
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
          +
        </button>
        <div>New Room</div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <button className="create-room-btn" type="submit">
          K
        </button>
        <div>Kitchen</div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <button className="create-room-btn" type="submit">
          H
        </button>
        <div>HoF</div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <button className="create-room-btn" type="submit">
          D
        </button>
        <div>Delivery</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: are you rendering this through React? If not `className` is not valid html, you need to just use `class`. Making just this change will allow the majority of you code to render as expected, though it will need tweaking.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for 1 :

for making a button exact circle you have to give the height of the button as is takes the width from the text inside it but the height remains consistent.

So instead of using this

```
button {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Use something like this (configure height as you want)

```
button {
  height: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Solution for 2:
To display something in a flex and in form of row you have to give the flow-direction

so in your case replace

```
.btn-newroom {
  display: flex;
}
```

by

```
.btn-newroom {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: "row";
}
```

If you want to have button and text as column use

```
.btn-newroom {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: "column";
}
```

Comment: `flex-direction` defaults to `row` if not specified, so not technically necessary in this case, but the explicit declaration is probably good to point out.